# apply a global CSS value to mobile view in foundation CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation css 5 to build a web application and it is wqorking perfect in tablet and desktop view. But when coming to mobile view it is not catching CSS properties which I have defined manually.

I checked in media queries and saw that CSS for mobile view is in `@media only screen { }`

If I want to add the same property to mobile view, do I need to add below code in `@media only screen {}`??

```
.mentoring-bg-color {
    background-color: #003B5D;
    color: #C9C9C7;
}
```

above is working for desktop and tablet view OR large and medium view.

Comment: you are right. But you have to mentioned the screen width in the media query. like `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 320px){}`

Comment: I am little confused now. Can you please tell me which is the min and max for mobile view?

Comment: @ManojKumar max for mobile view `max-width: 40em)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Foundation 5 media Queries](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html)

```
/* max-width 640px, mobile-only styles, use when QAing mobile issues */
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { 
   .mentoring-bg-color {
      background-color: #003B5D;
      color: #C9C9C7;
   }
}
```

The css `mentoring-bg-color` is apply only for mobile view.